# Condition number of a 3-Dimensional Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

We know well about how to calculate the **condition number**, $\kappa,$ of  two-dimensional matrices, but it seems that there is not enough said about, in higher dimensions.

So, how to calculate the condition number of following  $2 \times 2 \times 2 $ matrix $B$:

$$ B(:,:,1)=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1  \\
    5       & 3 \\  
\end{bmatrix}, $$

$$ B(:,:,2)=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    7       & 3  \\
    2       & 2 \\  
\end{bmatrix} .$$

Comment: First you will need a definition for "condition number" of a three-dimensional array.  (I don't say "matrix", since to me that means two-dimensional.)

Comment: Higher dimensional boxes of numbers are usually referred to as tensors. For super-symmetric tensors (tensors that are the same under any permutation of indices, e.g., derivative tensors), the natural generalization of condition number is the ratio of the largest tensor eigenvalue to the smallest tensor eigenvalue. For general nonsymmetric tensors things are a lot harder and I don't think there is a clear generalization. Here is a good paper to read for background on tensors in general: http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mlotz/teaching/nur/tensordecompositions.pdf

Comment: @NickAlger interesting read.